# Can't correctly place HTML5 Slider output

Tags: css, html, positioning, rangeslider

Not entirely sure how I can phrase this question correctly, my apologies for that.
What I want to happen here is that the "output" is displayed right next to the slider, and not beneath it.

To see what is wrong: alainbruno.nl/form.html

At any rate, I'm just starting with HTML5, and this is the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Character Creation</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        //Range
        var val     = $('#slider').val();
            output  = $('#output');

        output.html(val);

        $('#slider').on('change', function(){
            output.html(this.value);
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Appearance</legend>
<p>
<label>
Select Race:
</label>
<select id="Race">
<option value="human">Human</option>
<option value="faela">Faela</option>
<option value="domovoi">Domovoi</option>
<option value="arcon">Arcon</option>
<option value="tsaaran">Tsaaran</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
 <label>Select Gender</label>
<select id="Gender">
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option> 
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="range">Select Age:</label> <input type="range" min="14" max="60" id="slider"     value="10" name="range"> <div id="output"></div>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `<div>` that holds that value a `<span>` so it displays `inline`:

```
<p>
    <label for="range">Select Age:</label> 
    <input type="range" min="14" max="60" id="slider" value="10" name="range"> 
    <span id="output"></span>
</p>
```

See [this Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ELffjF?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/ELffjF?p=preview)

Alternatively, you could use css to set that `<div>` to `display:inline`, but that'd be an anti-patten IMHO, seeing as `<span>` exists, and is, by default `display:inline`